# PhpUnit runs indefinitely

Tags: cakephp, automated-tests, phpunit

None of the PHP Unit tests implemented run. 
It doesn't throw errors either.

No errors are logged and the test keeps running infinitely.

```
C:\xampp_v7.0\htdocs\...>vendor\bin\phpunit --verbose  tests\TestCase\Model\Table\UsersTableTest.php
PHPUnit 6.5.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

```
Runtime:       PHP 7.0.30 with Xdebug 2.5.5
Configuration: C:\xampp_v7.0\htdocs\...\phpunit.xml.dist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted MySql server and this was fixed.

Another possible reason could be

- Errors in the data loaded in Fixtures (Any syntax errors in the fixture files can lead to this situation) This can be identified by excluding all fixtures and including them one at a time and running the tests. Using this way the fixture that caused the issue can be found.